# Load popup after 30 seconds of browsing

Tags: javascript, popup, local-storage

I have a popup which is loaded after 30 seconds of viewing the homepage. Is it possible to have it load after 30 seconds of browsing the site and not just a particular page?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Current code still only loads the box after 30 seconds on each page load

```
var myDaemon = '';
localStorage.setItem('myTimestamp', Date.now());

if(myDaemon) clearInterval(myDaemon);
    myDaemon = setInterval(function(){
    var TimeDiffinSeconds = (Date.now() - localStorage.myTimestamp) / 1000;
    if( TimeDiffinSeconds > 30){
        requestcallback();
        clearInterval(myDaemon);
        localStorage.myTimestamp = Date.now();
    }
},1000);


function requestcallback(){
    // localStorage.clear();
    var popup
    if(localStorage["popup"] != null){
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime(),
            last_here = new Date();

        last_here.setTime(localStorage["popup"]);

        var current = last_here.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        if(current < timestamp){
            popup = setTimeout(showPopup, 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        popup = setTimeout(showPopup, 1);   
    }

    function showPopup(){
        jQuery('.overlay').fadeIn();
        clearTimeout(popup);    
    }

    jQuery('.overlay .close').click(function(){
        jQuery('.overlay').fadeOut();
        var current = new Date().getTime();
        localStorage["popup"] = current;    
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in order to save a time-stamp the moment the user visits the site , and then code a simple `SetInterval` to check that timestamp in specific intervals. If the difference between the current timestamp and the one saved is more than 30 seconds , you can launch your popup.

This is tricky with Javascript though. Depending on your Sites Design a different Approach is required. Also if it is for Security reasons , this is best done with AJAX and Validation through a Server. Javascript can be easily manipulated / prevented from a user and your code can be easily avoided.

A simple Example to get you going :

At your `index` page insert the following code :

```
<script>
  var myDaemon = '';
  localStorage.setItem('myTimestamp', Date.now());
</script>
```

We have declared a "`var myDaemon = '';`" so that we can hold our Daemons IDs in there and effectively Clearing them from any of our pages later.
Then at the Pages that you want to check for activity insert the following code :

```
 if(myDaemon) clearInterval(myDaemon);
 myDaemon = setInterval(function(){
   var TimeDiffinSeconds = (Date.now() - localStorage.myTimestamp) / 1000;
   if( TimeDiffinSeconds > 30){
     alert('You have been browsing for more than 30 Seconds');
     clearInterval(myDaemon);
     localStorage.myTimestamp = Date.now();
   }
 },1000);
```

- The  `if(myDaemon) clearInterval(myDaemon);` is there to make sure we do not overlap Daemons and end up with a million of Alerts after visiting a few pages.
- The `clearInterval(myDaemon);` after the alert is there to make sure that we stop the Daemon when we reach our goal.
- The `localStorage.myTimestamp = Date.now();` is there to make sure we reset our localstorage to a new Timestamp , in order to recalculate the activity of the user (if needed).

Comment: Thanks Strahdvonzar that really helps but it still only seem to work on individual pages, I still have to wait 30 seconds after each page load

Answer (score 1):

1) Define cookie functions (copy from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp))

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {...}
function getCookie(cname) {...}
function checkCookie() {...}
```

2) Create cookie if user doesn't have one

```
getCookie('user_first_visited') || setCookie('user_first_visited', Date.now());
```

3) Loop detecting if user visited over 30 seconds

```
if (!getCookie('user_popup_triggerred')) {
    var loopDetect = setInterval(function(){
        var TimePast = (Date.now() - getCookie('user_first_visited')) / 1000;
        if( TimePast > 5){
            alert('Browsed any page more than 5 Seconds');
            clearInterval(loopDetect);
            setCookie('user_popup_triggerred', 1);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns1z6cLu/), you can try it on two pages and you should not get popupBox on page reload after triggered once. Clean your browser cookie to try again.