# jQuery load modal after an interval only one time per session

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I would like to show a modal after 5 seconds, but only once per session (website visit).

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  //Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
  $("#bkgOverlay").delay(4800).fadeIn(400);
     //Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)
$("#delayedPopup").delay(5000).fadeIn(400);

//Hide dialouge and background when the user clicks the close button
$("#btnClose").click(function (e)
{
    HideDialog();
    e.preventDefault();
});
  });
//Controls how the modal popup is closed with the close button
function HideDialog()
{
$("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
$("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
 }
```

This is the codepen for it:
https://codepen.io/uxfed/pen/BmyeEr

I would like this modal to only show one time per website session.

Comment: You need to use database for that task. Maybe you're using some framework also?

Comment: cant javascript cookies be used for this? something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140363/load-popup-after-30-seconds-of-browsing/38140480

Comment: In this case user can come later and could  see your message again. Database checking prevents this by IP at least.

Comment: that's fine, Aksen, as long as it doesn't show on the current website session for all pages. Is there a way to incorporate the solution in that question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `fading` code into body of `if statement`. I did it via [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) tool. This code works for me:

---

```
    $(function(){ 

        console.log(window.localStorage);
        var ip_s = localStorage.getItem('ip'); 
        var d = new Date();

        !ip_s ? use_local_storage(d) : console.log('not the first visit');
    })

function use_local_storage(d) {

        $.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?', function(data) {

            var iip = String(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)).ip); 

            localStorage.setItem('ip', iip); 
            localStorage.setItem('day_visit', d.toLocaleDateString());

            console.log(window.localStorage);

           // load your function here   
           // question_body();

        });  
}
```

---

Code in Snippet doesn't works here, but in your project it would.

```js
function hideDialog(){
$("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
$("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
}

function question_body(){
            //Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
        $("#bkgOverlay").delay(4800).fadeIn(400);
            //Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)
        $("#delayedPopup").delay(5000).fadeIn(400);

            //Hide dialouge and background when the user clicks the close button
        $("#btnClose").click(function (e){
            HideDialog();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
}
 
$(function(){ 
     
    console.log(window.localStorage);
    var ip_s = localStorage.getItem('ip'); 
    var d = new Date();
    
    !ip_s ? use_local_storage(d) : console.log('not the first visit');
})

function use_local_storage(d) {

    $.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?', function(data) {

        var iip = String(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)).ip); 
         
        localStorage.setItem('ip', iip); 
        localStorage.setItem('day_visit', d.toLocaleDateString());

        console.log(window.localStorage);
         
       // load your function here   
       // question_body();
 
    });  
}
```

```css
.instructions {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  margin: 15vh;
}  

/* //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //   Default Modal Styles   //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
/*   This is the background overlay   */
.backgroundOverlay {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #000000;
 opacity: .85;
 filter: alpha(opacity=85);
 -moz-opacity: .85;
 z-index: 101;
 display: none;
}
/*   This is the Popup Window   */
.delayedPopupWindow {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 480px;
 height: 310px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -260px;
 margin-top: -180px;
 background-color: #efefef;
 border: 2px solid #333;
 z-index: 102;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
/*   This is the closing button  */
#btnClose {
 width:100%;
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #BCBCBC;
}
/*   This is the closing button hover state  */
#btnClose:hover {
 color: #c90c12;
}
/*   This is the description headline and paragraph for the form   */
#delayedPopup > div.formDescription {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 44%;
 padding: 1% 3%;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #666;
 clear: left;
}
/*   This is the styling for the form's headline   */
#delayedPopup > div.formDescription h2 {
 color: #444444;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/* 
////////// MailChimp Signup Form //////////////////////////////
*/

/*   This is the signup form body  */
#delayedPopup #mc_embed_signup {
 float: left;
 width: 47%;
 padding: 1%;
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #666;
 margin-left: 1%;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input {
 width: 95%;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs when they are being hovered with the mouse  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input:hover {
 border:solid 2px #40c348;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #AAAAAA;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs when they are focused  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input:focus {
 border:solid 2px #40c348;
 box-shadow: none;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form submit button  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe {
 width: 100%!important;
 height: 40px!important;
 margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
 background: #5D9E62;
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form submit button hover state  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
 background: #40c348;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow:none!important;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="instructions">Wait for 5 seconds</div>

<div id="bkgOverlay" class="backgroundOverlay"></div>
  
<div id="delayedPopup" class="delayedPopupWindow">
  <!-- This is the close button -->
  <a href="#" id="btnClose" title="Click here to close this deal box.">[ X ]</a>
  <!-- This is the left side of the popup for the description -->
  <div class="formDescription">
    <h2>Sign Up and <span style="color: #40c348; font-weight: bold;">Save $25!</span></h2>
    <p>Sign up for our Deal Alerts and save
      $25 Off of your first order of $50 or more!</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
  <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name
          <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name
          <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address
          <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
      </div>

      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
        <input type="text" name="b_2aabb98e55b83ba9d3bd551f5_e6c08b53b4" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Save Money!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- End MailChimp Signup Form -->
</div>
```